# Spring Boot add UI with React

Tags: reactjs, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Rest Api project which i did CRUD methods with my 2 entity classes. I want to add UI this project with react. But i am new Reactjs, i dont know very well.
Here my Rest-Api controller and sample methods:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = { "http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:4200" })
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;

    @GetMapping("/list")

    public ResponseEntity<List<Student>> ListStudents() {

        List<Student> theStudent = studentService.getStudents();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(theStudent, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getStudent/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Student> getStudentById(@PathVariable("id") int theId) {

        Student theStudent = studentService.getStudentById(theId);
        return new ResponseEntity<Student>(theStudent, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I set up react my computer and created a new project. But now I don't know what i do with this. How can i connect React and my Rest-Api project. Please help me what should i do?

Comment: u have to send an http request by axios or fetch api to ur api and get the response and then show it in the way u want in a stateful component of react

Answer (score 0):

as I mentioned in the comments, u have to send an HTTP request to ur api.

u can do it by axios or fetch or even XMLHttpRequest.

then u have to get the response (cast it if it is a json, u can do it with json2typescript library to cast the json to a class model) and then change the state of ur react component by setState and show data in the page.

personally, my choice is fetch api and here an example of working with fetch:

```
const response = fetch('server_URL:port/student', {method: "get"}).then(res => console.log(res));
```

here is a more complete tutorial using axios: https://hackernoon.com/tutorial-how-to-make-http-requests-in-react-part-3-daa6b31b66be

**--update--**

here u can find about react states and components (also u can find examples) https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Thanks my friend i used fetch in componentDidMount method like this. `fetch('http://localhost:8080/student/list')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({students: data})
            })` it is working but i dont know how can i add buttons for post methods or how can edit my students please you can share little example for me? Again thanks for helping.

Comment: u have to create a component that holds ur button and the state of it, then after u get the response u have to change its state, for more detail u can check the example link i put in my post